# R: select columns with NAs for mutate function

Tags: r, na, dplyr

I'm trying to subset columns in my dataframe to use them solely in a mutate function as part of conditional formating for an HTML Table with knitr::kable and kableExtra.

```
#Conditional Formating function
highlights <- function(x) { cell_spec(x, background = ifelse( x != NA, "#C9FFE5","white")) }

#build table
ds.tab <- ds%>%
  mutate_if("column contains ANY NA values", funs(highlights(.)))%>% ...
```

I need to write the bit between brackets (**"column contains ANY NA values"**)  in R.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at `is.na`.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you use `any(is.na(.))` such as the following:

```
ds.tab <- ds %>%
  mutate_if(function(x) any(is.na(x)), funs(highlights(.))) %>% ...
```

Or if you prefer, the following syntax works the same way

```
ds.tab <- ds %>%
  mutate_if(~any(is.na(.)), funs(highlights(.))) %>% ...
```

Comment: Without any other arguments needed or anything, the `funs()` isn't needed. `mutate_if(~any(is.na(.)), highlights)` should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you but it all returns: Error in if (substr(color, 1, 1) != "#" | nchar(color) != 9) return(color) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: That's an issue in your `highlights` function then. Try `is.na(x)` (and never `x != NA`) instead